# How to make Evernote support code syntax highlight and formatting?

Tags: formatting, evernote

I use Evernote as my [PKM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_knowledge_management); it's just so convenient and it's cross-platform. It's a pity that code in HTML page is not supported perfectly in Evernote.

It sucks if we paste code directly into Evernote; formatting and syntax highlighting will both be lost. I try to paste code into another website which support them (e.g., Github's  "gist") and then copy from it, but this still remains useless.

Is there a better and convenient way to make Evernote support code formatting better so that I can use it as a code library?

Comment: `Not supported perfectly` and `it sucks`? Which one is it?

Comment: What is the status quo of code support? How does it turn out when you use gists?

Comment: Would this help [Cheeatz](http://www.cheeatz.com/)

Comment: @Raystafarian Cool!

Comment: Does it do what you need? Should I put it as an answer?

Comment: I'm still finding a reliable/stable/common way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The method that I've found that works best for me (although it is a bit of a kludge) is to email my Evernote account the code as a .txt file, or alternately wrapped by the `<code></code>` HTML tags in the body of the email. I've got just over 3000 notes incorporating this sort of format. Most of what I've used this for is HTML, Javascript and Ruby on Rails files.

It seems that the email-to-note gateway treats the content just a little differently than just cutting and pasting it in my experience. The one caveat I would offer is that this method probably will not work if you are using XML structures, due to the native file structure of native notes. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, right before HTML in the first paragraph, it should have a less-than symbol, the word 'code', a greater-than symbol, the words "code here" and then a less-than symbol, a forward slash, the word 'code', and a greater-than symbol. I've not mastered how to insert notation like that here, so that's my bad! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to use the Markdown Here plugin for Firefox/Chrome/Safari. It works only in Evernote Web, but you get the full power of Markdown right inside the Evernote editor. The syntax looks like this:

````
```java
int foo = 9;
```
````

Comment: At least link to the plugin.